# MessageBox и String в visual studio 2012 (C++/CLR)

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Есть написанный консольный код. Нужно перенести это все в графический интерфейс. Подскажите пожалуйста,как правильно выводить сообщение в диалоговое окно в visual studio 2012?
Я читал, что нужно использовать `MessageBox::show`. Но он принимает объект класса `String^`. Перегруженного для обычного string насколько я понял нету. Скажите как правильно здесь выводить сообщения?
И что делать, если весь код уже написан с использованием обычной `string`? 
Насколько я понимаю символ `^` это ссылочный тип, чтобы NET привязать.

Comment: Есть методы преобразования string в System::String^

Comment: То есть это всегда надо будет преобразовывать чтобы выводит на экран ?

Comment: Угу, всегда. Это, по идее, несложно, что-то вроде

    gcnew System::String(yourstring.c_str())

Или в программе использовать `System::String^` вместо `std::string`

Comment: Спасибо уже написал , в отдельном файле функции конвертации